# wscript access denied but cscript works

Tags: wsh

I have a simple vbs script that popups a message

```
Msgbox("Here")
```

I can run it using cscript

```
cscript hello.vbs
```

and it works fine. But if I try to run it using wscript, I get an error saying "Access is denied". How can I get it to run with wscript?

thanks

Comment: _Whether you use `WScript` or `CScript`, you still run the scripts in the same manner. The difference is only in the output_. Please [edit] the question and share the way you _try to run it using `wscript`_. Show result of `where ?script` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Cscript.exe is a command-line version of the Windows Script Host.

By Design "Windows Script Host supports scripts written in VBScript or JScript.".

It can run hello.vbs because this file is a VB Script.

And again by design, I cannot run a WScript which is a windows Shell script.

WScript by itself can be executed and does not need other programs to run it.